# Basic Python Class

Tags: python, class, init

Im just try to build a basic class so that I can learn some more about python.
So far I have the following :

```
class Bodymassindex:
  count = 0
  def __init__(self,name,weight,height):
    self.name = name
    self.weight = 14 * weight
    self.height = 12 * height
    notes = "no notes have been assigned yet"
    bmitotal = 0
    Bodymassindex.count += 1

  def displayCount(self):
    print "Total number of objects is %d" % Bodymassindex.count

  def notesBmi(self,text):
    self.notes = text

  def calcBmi(self):
    return ( self.weight * 703 ) / ( self.height ** 2 )
```

In terms of adding a note variable and viewing what is the correct way of doing so ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's worth noting [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests ``CapWords`` for class names and ``lowercase_with_underscores`` for function names. It's also worth noting that 'setters like ``notesBmi`` are not worth using in Python - make it an attribute and use it like one. If you need to do something there later, use [``property()``](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: When using python 2.x, it is often desireable to inherit from `object` ... e.g.  `class Bodymassindex(object):`

Comment: @mgilson: *often*? It is *always* desirable.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Yes -- Though for very basic scripts, you'll often not notice the difference and you can save a little typing by not putting it in there.  But I agree.  It is the best practice.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan not if you're building something which will be used as a mixin with a library that only provides old-style classes. That's rare, and to be avoided, but violates "always".

Comment: @mgilson Please don't propagate the existence of old-style classes (thus forcing folks to build _more_ old-style classes for the sake of interoperating with them!) just to save a little typing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: it is always desirable. It may not be possible in remote cases of very old code (which needs updating), but that doesn't stop it from being desirable!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan sadly, some of that very old code is still in the standard library as of Python 2.7; ftplib, difflib, cookielib, mimewriter, pickle, calendar, optparse, and quite a few others all have old-style classes (even if not exclusively). I fully agree that new-style classes are always desirable where they can be used, but they can't be used everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the attribute:

```
class BodyMassIndex(object): #Inheriting from object in 2.x ensures a new-style class.
  count = 0
  def __init__(self, name, weight, height):
    self.name = name
    self.weight = 14 * weight
    self.height = 12 * height
    self.notes = None
    self.bmitotal = 0
    BodyMassIndex.count += 1

  def display_count(self):
    print "Total number of objects is %d" % BodyMassIndex.count

  def calculate_bmi(self):
    return ( self.weight * 703 ) / ( self.height ** 2 )

test = BodyMassIndex("bob", 10, 10)
test.notes = "some notes"
print(test.notes)
```

There is nothing wrong with direct access in Python. As others have noted, it's likely you meant to make `notes` and `bmitotal` instance variables, which I have done here.

Comment: It might be a better idea to set `notes` to `None` initially to make testing for the "no notes" case easier.

Comment: @larsmans This is good advice, I was simply sticking to what the OP did. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

The `bmitotal` and `notes` variables in `__init__` will be local and garbage collected when `__init__` finishes, so initializing them like that is useless. You probably want to initialize them as `self.notes` and `self.bmitotal`

`Bodymassindex.count` would be *like* a static variable, which *shares* its value with all the instances.

Comment: Also note that `Bodymassindex.count` can be reset on an instance...e.g. `self.count = 5` which will not update the "static version".

Comment: yes, that's why i said `*like* a static variable` ;) i didn't want to confuse him too much.

Comment: @mgilson That's not true - it's not reset, rather, ``self.count`` will point to ``Bodymassindex.count`` unless there is an instance variable called count, in which case it points to that.

Comment: Actually `BodyMassIndex.count` will always be *static*, if you try to reference an instance variable with the same name as the *static* variable and it doesn't exist (like inst.count), you get the *static* value. If you set the instance variable and reference it with `inst.count` you obviously get the property value. But if you reference `BodyMassIndex.count`, even if you initialize the instance variable, you'll still get the *static* value. Is it confusing you already? :P

Comment: @Lattyware how is that different than resetting *on an instance*?  Maybe we're just disagreeing on semantics...Perhaps I should have said "reset for an instance"?

Comment: @mgilson The instance property and the class property are completely different objects. The only catch here is that when you call the instance property and it doesn't exist you get the class property object instead.

Comment: and @KurzedMetal of course you can always retrieve the "static (class)" attribute by literally using `Bodymassindex.count` instead of `self.count`

Comment: @mgilson It's as KurzedMetal states, saying the variable is reset implies that the variable is changing, it's nothing to do with that variable, what changes is what ``self.count`` means in the context of the program. If ``self.count`` doesn't exist as an instance variable, it means the static variable ``BodyMassIndex.count``, otherwise it means the instance variable.

Comment: I just avoid using class properties at all when designing classes to avoid shooting at my foot :P

Comment: I was really only trying to point out that a class can contain a "class attribute" and an "instance attribute".  I guess I should be more careful what terms I use...  Sorry for any confusion I might have caused.